# What is the delegate method called when the URLSessionDownloadTask start?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

There are three methods in `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` protocol.

```
URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:,
URLSession:downloadTask:didResumeAtOffset:expectedTotalBytes:
URLSession:downloadTask:downloadTaskdidWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:
```

The `didFinishDownloadingToURL` is called when the download task complete. But what is the method called when the download task start?

Answer (score 1):

URLSession:downloadTask:downloadTaskdidWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:
this delegate gets called time to time depending on data received, this delegates writes data to file location. furthermore, if anything goes wrong, 
–URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: 
this delegate gives you details about the error.

Comment: As workaround, I add the stuff in `URLSession:downloadTask:downloadTaskdidWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`. I add a flag and init with NO, once the method called, the flag turn YES.

Comment: Why dont you add count and increment it there, you'll get exact idea of how many times delegate gets called...